# Crear un query que no duplique datos en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes quisiera saber como hacer un query que me salga algo asi

```
  SELECT 
    Paciente= HC.IdPaciente ,
    Fecha_Adm = CONVERT(char(10), E.FechaAdmision, 101),
    Activo =  CASE WHEN  E.Estado = 'Activo' THEN 1 END ''end,
    Anulado = CASE WHEN E.Estado = 'Anulado' THEN 1 END '' END,
    Estado =  CASE WHEN E.Estado = 'Anulado' THEN 'Solo Anulado' 
                  WHEN E.Estado = 'Activado' and E.Estado= 'Anulado'  
                  THEN 'Activado'  ELSE 'Activado' END
    FROM dbo.VW_SA_EM_REP_ListadoAtencionEmergencia E
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Paciente HC ON  E.CodigoHC = HC.CodigoHC    
    WHERE 
        Year(FechaAdmision)=2018 
        AND Month(FechaAdmision)=08
        AND TipoAtencion= 'Emergencia'
        AND E.Sucursal = 'CEG'
            GROUP BY  HC.IdPaciente, 
                CONVERT(char(10), E.FechaAdmision, 101), 
                CASE WHEN  E.Estado = 'Activo' THEN 1 ELSE ''END,
                CASE WHEN  E.Estado = 'Anulado' THEN 1 ELSE ''END,
                CASE WHEN E.Estado = 'Anulado' THEN 'Solo Anulado' 
                     WHEN E.Estado = 'Activado' and E.Estado= 'Anulado'  THEN 'Activado'  ELSE 'Activado' END
                ORDER BY Paciente, Fecha_Adm
```

RESULTADO DEL QUERY

```
`Idpaciente` `fecha_Admision` `activo` `anulado`
    `28`         `10/10/2018`    `1`      `0`
    `28`         `10/10/2018`    `0`      `1`
    `29`         `10/10/2018`    `1`      `0`
    `29`         `19/10/2018`    `0`      `1`
```

--> y lo que se quiere es que envez que salga asi salga asi:

```
`Idpaciente` `fecha_Admision` `activo` `anulado`
    `28`         `10/10/2018`    `1`      `1`
    `29`         `19/10/2018`    `1`      `1`
```

[Seleccionar aqui para ver el ejemplo](http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyZWbwLTuG10ICY6Dabnx80yXtHQcMhhK1P6rzYrNYQ/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: intenta agregando en tu WHERE HC.IdPaciente IS NULL

Comment: Los datos desaparece ya que si pongo que si el HC.IDPACIENTE ES NULO OSE SOLO ESTOY AGARRANDO LOS DATOS NULOS

Comment: disculpa crei que insertabas. entonces intenta agregando ´DISTINCT´  en tu select

Comment: @ChristianGuerraHuertas recomendación es colocar todas las tabla que estas colocando los datos que tienen y su atributo y asi poder ayudarte. nosostros no sabemos que tienes.

Comment: @PieroDev puse los campos correspondiente a la consulta solo obvie el campo `estado` ya que supuse que se les haría mas complicado pero es lo mismo si miran el query lo que indico en el estado es que si el paciente de una fecha esta activo se llame activo y si tiene activo y anulado que se llame activo pero si esta el estado anulado que se llame solo anulado

Comment: @JuanL Consulta como puedo poner el `distinct` en mi query ya que estoy usando `group by`

Comment: se supone que distinct no es necesario con el group by, pero viendo vien la informacion que quieres de salida. por ejemplo en Idpaciente, veo que en tus campos `activo` `anulado` son de valor distinto, entonces deverias agregar un filtro, no se. `activo` <> 0  o de plano `anulado` <> 0

Comment: Lo puse pero no hay resultado alguno ya que si no hay 0 en activado no habra modificacion y si no hay 0 en anulado va a ser efecto lo mismo :/

Comment: @ChristianGuerraHuertas pon los datos que tienes en esas tablas que consultas para ayudarte.

Comment: Si quieres obtener un resultado como el que muestras, lo que debes hacer es agrupar solamente por los campos `idPaciente` y `FechaAdmisión`. Para las otras columnas, puedes utilizar las funciones `max()`, `sum()` o incluso `count()`. Usualmente escribiría una respuesta con el SQL, pero en este caso, la consulta que publicas en la pregunta _no produce los resultados_ que muestras, de hecho, tiene errores de sintaxis. Por eso no escribo la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues si entendí bien, deberías hacer algo asi:

```
SELECT 
Paciente= HC.IdPaciente ,
Fecha_Adm = CONVERT(char(10), E.FechaAdmision, 101),
Activo =  SUM(CASE WHEN E.Estado = 'Activo' THEN 1 else 0 END),
Anulado = SUM(CASE WHEN E.Estado = 'Anulado' THEN 1 else 0 END),
Estado =  CASE WHEN MIN(E.Estado) = 'Anulado' THEN 'Solo Anulado' 
              WHEN MAX(E.Estado) <> MIN(E.Estado) THEN 'Hay anulados y activos' 
              ELSE 'Activado' END
FROM dbo.VW_SA_EM_REP_ListadoAtencionEmergencia E
LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Paciente HC ON  E.CodigoHC = HC.CodigoHC    
WHERE 
    Year(FechaAdmision)=2018 
    AND Month(FechaAdmision)=08
    AND TipoAtencion= 'Emergencia'
    AND E.Sucursal = 'CEG'
        GROUP BY  HC.IdPaciente, 
            CONVERT(char(10), E.FechaAdmision, 101), 
            ORDER BY Paciente, Fecha_Adm
```

En el ultimo campo no entendi bien que necesitas, pero en caso de que tengas registros activos e inactivos coloqué 'Hay anulados y activos', cambialo por el mensaje que consideres.

Puede que tenga algun error de sintaxis o algo, como no lo puedo probar...

Comment: Gracias la única observación que le di es en vez de `COUNT` le puse `SUM`, ya que me contaba los activos o anulados mas no me lo sumaba pero lo demás excelente.